# HTA value update freezes when file copy starts

Tags: vbscript, hta

Creating an HTA that will automate the installation of several applications
it starts by checking for the existence of certain files then copies a large folder to local from a flash drive if it doesn't exist, I have a textbox I'm using to update the current status of the script, but it just seems to freeze and never updates, I haven't had any luck with any of the artificial sleep functions either.

here's the segment

```
If Not objFSO.FileExists(Office10Dir) Then
MsgBox("Excel is missing")

BasicTextBox.Value = "Office14 Not Detected, Copying Source Files to Local"

Dim objFS, objFolder
Dim OfficeTemp
OfficeTemp = "C:\OfficeTemp"
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFS.CreateFolder(OfficeTemp)
objFS.CopyFolder "OfficeTemp", "C:\OfficeTemp"

BasicTextBox.Value = "Local Temp Directory Created"

ELSE
MsgBox("Excel is Installed")
END IF
```

All i see is the "Local Temp Directory Created" message once file copy is complete

Comment: Thats all you will see surely? you update the text *after* the copy is complete, what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies guys, I was able to get the desired result using a 'CopyHere' method and declaring a constant to update the progress bar of file copy progress.

```
'copies files from current dir 'OfficeTemp' to local
Dim objFS, objFolder, oShell, oTarget
Dim OfficeTemp
OfficeTemp = "C:\OfficeTemp"
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFS.CreateFolder(OfficeTemp)

Const FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = &H0&

strTargetFolder = "C:\OfficeTemp" 

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(strTargetFolder) 

objFolder.CopyHere "OfficeTemp\*.*", FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "CopyFolder" you can create the destination folder, then iterate through the file objects.

```
<script>
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objOfficeTemp = objFS.GetFolder("C:\OfficeTemp")

If Not objFS.FolderExists("C:\SomeDestination") Then
  objFS.CreateFolder("C:\SomeDestination")
End If

For Each objOfficeTempFile In objOfficeTemp.Files
  'copy the file
  'add some logic that updates your hta
  'if you have nested folders, you'll
  'have to copy them recursively...

  objOfficeTempFile.Copy "C:\SomeDestination"

  updatespan.innerhtml = "Copying file: " & objOfficeTempFile.Name
Next
</script>


<html>
<body>
<span id="updatespan">&nbsp;</span>
</body>
</html>
```